# Flutter Timer only updating the seconds not hours and minutes

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am working on a stopwatch application using Flutter, I am done with the UI Part and the logic, but the app has an issue that is only the seconds part is running, the minutes and hours are not. Here is the screenshot of my app:

[Flutter Stopwatch app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt6il.png)

Here is my code:

[Flutter Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5zt1.png)

Hope anyone have any solution and if have please rectify this error...

Comment: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/stopwatch-timer-in-flutter-70afa58d88e5

Comment: String _printDuration(Duration duration) {
  String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
  String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
  String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
  return "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
}